# Fileupload control display

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how do we need to code a fileupload control so that it appears same in all browsers. Each browser shows the fileupload button in different ways. How do we need to code the CSS so that it displays the same in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use CSS to 'trick' the browsers into covering the file upload control with your own label/buttons in order to create the appearance that it is styled the same across multiple browsers.

http://the-echoplex.net/log/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-control-using-css-and-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this plugin:
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader
It is a multiple file upload plugin with progress-bar, drag-and-drop.
Homepage:
http://fineuploader.com